# Lyapunov Stability for a Nonlinear, Time-varying system

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

I am currently trying to learn how to determine the stability of a solution using Lyapunov's Method for non-autonomous systems.

Say we are given a nonlinear system:
$$\dot{x_1}(t)=-x_1(t) + x_2(t)[x_1(t)+g(t)]$$
$$\dot{x_2}(t)= x_1(t)[x_1(t)+g(t)]$$
And we want to investigate the stability of the solution $x(t)=0$.

If we use a simple Lyapunov function
$$V(x) = 0.5x_{1}^{2} + 0.5x_{2}^{2}$$

I can find $\dot{V}(x,t)$, but I am unsure of where to go from here. How do I prove some kind of stability/instability. Do I need Barbalat's Lemma?

Comment: You could look at the case when $g(t)=0$ and if that is stable use vanishing perturbation.

Comment: I think you might have mistaken a $-$ sign with $+$